Problem adding SVG elements dynamically and rendering them using React Signals
I am trying to dynamically add SVG elements to my screen using React Signals. I now have a situation in which I do not get any errors anymore, but the dynamically added SVG elements do not render. I also use a statically added SVG element for test and that one does render. It seems like what is added to the Signal variable are objects and not the pure SVG "strings" Reacts needs to be able to render the SVG. But, even if this is the problem, I can not figure out how to extract from the Signal value what react needs to indeed render the SVG elements. Here's the involved code. Advice would be much appreciated!
import { useSignal } from '@preact/signals-react';
import { useSignals } from '@preact/signals-react/runtime';

const FamiliezBewerken = () => {
    useSignals();

    // Create a signal for the array of person elements
    const setOfPersonElements = useSignal([]);

    // Create a new person element and add it to the signal value
    const addPersonElement = () => {
        const newPersonElement = (
            <rect
                key={Math.random()} // Add a unique key
                x={Math.random() * 100}
                y={Math.random() * 100}
                width={120}
                height={60}
                fill="white"
            />
        );
        setOfPersonElements.value.push(newPersonElement);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={addPersonElement}>Add Person Element</button>
            <svg width="100%" height="100%">
                {/* The following line included for test and it renders */}
                <rect x={Math.random() * 100} y={Math.random() * 101} width={120} height={60} fill="white" />
                {/* This next one does not */} 
                {setOfPersonElements.value}
            </svg>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FamiliezBewerken;

So I used CoPilot to figure out what is wrong. That made me turn in circles. The code included above by now is pretty much 1-on-1 what CoPilot advised. I also looked into the "Review questions already on Stack Overflow....", but those do not use Signals, so do not seems to be helpfull for my case.

Signals cannot contain JSX elements, there's no real way to make this work. Signals are meant to contain primitives like strings, numbers, booleans, etc. Because of this, setOfPersonElements.value.push also wouldn't work, as you can only change the value of a signal using assignment (setOfPersonElements.value = ...)

Hmmm, not able to test it now, need to do that when I am behind my workstation again. But if memory serves me correct, I was indeed able to push the SVG rect object onto the array contained in the Signal var. This seems to contradict what you say regarding using assignment. As said, will come back on this. It would be a total bummer if indeed Signals are not fit for what I want to do in this case :-(.  To be continued.

Full disclosure, I'm one of Signal's maintainers. Signals are state, and are to be used in a similar way that you'd use hooks. If you wouldn't add JSX elements to useState (and you absolutely should not, to be clear) then you shouldn't try to do so with signals. .push will "work" but nothing watching that signal will update.

Thanks for your reply. I understand. What I am trying to do (just for pleasure) is to build a app to manage family trees. I want to do that by making each person a (svg) control and connect them by (svg) lines/paths. This means I must be able to dynamically delete or add those controle (a.k.a. persons). When I do this, as far as I understand up until now, I would be changing state, but keep that in one screen / one url. But I might be very wrong in this. What would be the general approach you would advice for this case if not using state?
